# Cold start issues with EFI : have to start twice

Tags: mitsubishi, cold-start

I have a Galant 2003 with a 2.0l 4G63 engine. Since I refueled my car, issues started to arise.

First the car gave sudden knock and the engine check light turned on. From then onward, the car's performance dropped to nothing, which was fixed by an engine tuneup reset and an inclusion of Soltron fuel treatment enzyme.

But after that, I have noticed that the car's cold start was not as it used to be. I have to start the car at least two times, as on the first cold start the RPMs drop and the car turns off.

I don't know if this is cause by the failure of the air flow sensor, the tuning or the battery or if it is an entirely another problem. What should I be looking for?

Comment: If the only indication is problematic cold starts, maybe the mixture isn't rich enough, for whatever reason.

Comment: My first thought is you need to do a throttle position sensor (TPS) reset, but that's just a gut check. The idle air control valve may need to be cleaned as well.

Comment: @Paul May be thats the case. I will be filling her up with a higher octane from a different gas station aswel and try my luck :) thank you for the response

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks for the response :) I will take it to the garage and get these checked.. hopefully nothing serious :)

Comment: Could be that your EGR is malfunctioning.

Comment: @You_Shall_Not_Pass thank you for the reply and I will check on this as well :) may I know what may cause EGR to malfunction? does it happen with age or does it have special circumstances that could break this? thank you :)

Comment: Well, ummm.. Lots of reasons are there. even a software complaint or a faulty relay could cause the egr malfunction. But i MUST say that I DO NOT know what really  causes the malfunctioning of the EGR. But I have come across many cars with same issues as yours and many mechanics suggesting that fixing an EGR will solve the isses. It could also be that your egr is just fine, but signals/power is not reaching it and it doesn't know that  it needs to start.

Comment: Btw, yes, age could be a reason too..

Comment: @You_Shall_Not_Pass ohh I see.. I will check on this and thank you for the quick response.. I will get the car to the local garage and get those checked ..thanks for the headsup :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use some acceleration after start (about 10% of throttle pedal). If it helps then check your idle air control valve

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply :) i will get this checked and post back asap

Comment: "which was fixed by an engine tuneup" - do you mean ECU tuneup? Your idle valve might be controlled from ECU, so it can be also related to ECU setup (firmware) and valve itself is totally ok. Please also check wiring to valve wasn't it forgotten to connect

Comment: ohh okey will do :) I am not pretty sure which..but the reset was done by resetting the settings via a device connected to the car from the obd2 port :)

Comment: Hi, giving a bit of gas as soon as the car starts gets rid of the issue.. I think your solution most probably work.. I will get this checked :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I've seen these symptoms once before.  In that particular case it turned out to be a failing igniter/power transistor.  Went on for nearly 2 years before the cause was isolated, but the igniter module had developed a crack and was arcing badly on first start, but somehow working properly on second start.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. with this info i can now quickly ask the garage to check on it..thank you very much :)